# How to unbind a paticular binding in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 functions(**abc** and **def**) inside which I have attached a `submit()` event to an element, as follows:

```
function abc(param_1, param_2) {
  jQuery('#element_id').one("submit", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    someOtherFunction(param_1, param_2);
  });
}
```

and

```
function def() {
  jQuery('#element_id').one("submit", function(e){
    some other code
  });
}
```

**PROBLEM**: I need the `submit()` binding inside function **def** to execute every time, but based on some condition I may need to unbind the `submit()` binding inside function **abc** only. How can I achieve this?

**Note**: In no way I can check a condition(if - else) before binding `submit()` to element inside **abc** and **def**, as the condition is achieved dynamically. If it happens, I don't want `submit` block inside function **abc** to execute.

Comment: `.one` will `bind` the `event` only once. So you can use `.on` and `.off` to `bind` and `unbind`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao 1> I need to use `one()` 2> Using `off()` will unbind the entire `submit` event.

Comment: @Abhi: so, you want to unbind the submit event from function "abc" but not from "def"?

Comment: @Abhi, jquery allows you to add events specifically, for example, "submit.abc", and "submit.def", and accordingly, you can use .off("submit.abc") . It allows this kind of namespacing of events.

Comment: @Shivi Ok I'll try that. Meanwhile, it will be great if you can answer it with a working example

Comment: @Abhi: check-out  this simple plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QIQX5m?p=preview

Comment: @Shivi Thanks, it may solve my problem. I just need to figure out a way to make it work with `one()` instead of `on()`

Comment: @Abhi: just added the same as answer for record. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery allows to add events with namespace, so, we can add events.namespace, and accordingly deal with the binding and turning individual events off.

For more information, refer to: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

So, the same submit could be re-written as `"submit.abc"` and `"submit.def"`, and then `.off("submit.abc")`.